# Accessing JSON data when response contains both JSON data and text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, content-type

Initially the content from the server was JSON data.And I was able to access the data perfectly.

```
{ "status":"ok", "artifact":"weblayer-war", "version":"0.0.41-test-data", "buildtime":"test-data" }
```

Now the response from the server has been changed to json data + text data.

```
{ "status":"ok", "artifact":"weblayer-war", "version":"0.0.41-test-data", "buildtime":"test-data" }

Properties for service:
=======================
ServiceEndpoint: https://somedomain:1200/web/Servlet/SOAP/Services
Certificates: false
DocumentName: note.pdf
```

So whether changing the content-type to application-text and using split method is the only way we can solve this or Is there any better approach?

Comment: Maybe just take the first line of the response and parse it as JSON? Content type is irrelevant here, it's still text output so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Wow, who designed that API? Returning a formatted response and ALSO some arbitrary text undermines the idea of the formatted response. Your only option is to parse the JSON out yourself, yes.

Comment: You won't be getting any reponse... try getting it out in interceptor in the data param of the config as config.data or try consoling the config object to get better clue... if you are getting it there...

Comment: Thanks mark.I will try that.

Comment: I've added the response. If it solves your problem, please accept it, so the question could be marked as answered.

Comment: Thanks Utkanos for the clarity.

Comment: @kailas I am getting the 200 response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, mixing JSON and pure text data is wrong (as it defeats the advantage of using standardized data format) and should be avoided. Maybe that is some kind of debug log that was accidentally included in the production code?

If not, you should read just the first line of response and parse it as JSON data, ignoring the rest, hoping for no more changes in response structure ;)

Answer (score 0):

You really should overthink your API design.

What about adding the text part as part of your JSON?

```
{
    ... // your JSON properties here
    "serviceProperties": { // properties for service
        "ServiceEndpoint": "https://somedomain:1200/web/Servlet/SOAP/Services",
        "Certificates": false,
        "DocumentName": "note.pdf"
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the service response structure.